# Find value in a non-continuous range in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, lookup, range, named-ranges

Is there a way in Excel to look for a numeric value in a non-continuous range throughout the table?

Please refer to the image below:

[image]

I need to search for the value 2 between the range minimum value and maximum value throughout the table. Here 2 lies in the range 1.93-2.286 so the displayed output will be 3rd. How is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The below works for your sample data set, enter this into Cell `B3`:

```
{=INDEX($G$3:$G$6,MAX(IF(B1<IF(B1>$E$3:$E$6,$F$3:$F$6,0),ROWS($H$3:$H$6),0)),1)}
```

Adjust the ranges for your full data set and let me know how you get on.

Enter it as an array by pressing `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`

To make changes to suit your range, change the ROWS number. i.e `$G$3:$G$6` for rows 3 to 6 and `$G$3:$G$10` for rows 3 to 10, do this for columns E, F, G & H in the formula.

Then you can drag this down if you have values in B2, B3 etc..

Comment: Thanks. I am sightly unclear on the formula. What values/formula to enter in cell H3:H6? And will this formula work if I have to search for multiple values in the lookup table? For eg instead of the single value in B1 if i  have multiple values from cell B1:B6 to search in the lookup table then what to do?

Comment: @Anajz see update to answer and formula, you should be able to drag this down now as i have included $s in the ranges.

Answer (score 1):

You might be willing to try the following:

Step 1. In column H, next to each min-max-display value, create a helper column with this formula: `=IF(AND($B$1>=E3,$B$1<=F3),1,0)`. Drag down to extend to all table. This will output 1 if the value is in each range, 0 if not.

Step 2. In column H, just down of the last cell of the table (in this example, cell H7), please insert this formula: `=IF(COUNTIF(H3:H6,1)>0,0,1)`. This will set up as 1 if the above are all 0, this is, the "*not in any range*" case. Place any suitable text in G7.

Step 3. In cell B2, please enter the following formula: `=LOOKUP(1,H3:H7,G3:G7)`. This will output the appropriate display value, including the "*not in any range*" one.

Comment: Thanks!  Now if instead of a single value I have a column of values to search in the lookup table then how to do that?